# Allow CORS in Wordpress getting meetup API

Tags: wordpress

Im having trouble allowing cross site. I am adding meetup api into some wordpress pages. 
I added the header and .htaccess, respectively.
`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain.com");`

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain.com`

I have themes and other plugins installed. Is there a particular place I am suppose to insert the headers? Not sure where else I should look.